# Unable to get boundingBox from result for a request VNCoreMLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, apple-vision

I'm trying to use Vision with a custom model I trained, but I don't see a way to get the bounding box where Vision detected it in the frame.

The model: I've trained the model using CreateML, and it can detect 2 specific items.
I tested the model in CreateML with various images and it detects the 2 items correctly and places a box around them. So, shouldn't Vision be able to give me the bounding box as well?

```swift
func prepare() {
    do {
        let vnModel = try VNCoreMLModel(for: modelFile.model)
        let coreMlRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: vnModel,
                                            completionHandler: { (request, error) in
            guard
                let results = request.results
                    as? [VNClassificationObservation]  // is this the right cast?
            else { return }

            // how do I get the bounding box from the results?
        })
        vnRequests = [coreMlRequest]
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func run(arFrame: ARFrame) {
    do {
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: arFrame.capturedImage,
                                                   options: [:])
        try requestHandler.perform(self.vnRequests)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually train an object detection model? Or a classification model?

You only get bounding boxes for the object detection model, not for a classifier.

Assuming you trained an object detector, the correct class is `VNRecognizedObjectObservation`, not `VNClassificationObservation`.

Comment: I'm very new to CoreML, it's my first model. It's possible I didn't do it correctly.
I labeled 50 images, by placing a rect around the items I would like to train.
When I try the model inside CreateML, it finds the items and places an accurate rect around them, so I'm guessing it was trained for object detection.

Comment: That sounds correct. :-) You should be getting `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` results then.

Comment: ‘VNRecognizedObjectObservation’ did the trick. Thank you.